# Opening .out files in Python

Tags: python, ioerror

Am I right in thinking Python cannot open and read from .out files?

My application currently spits out a bunch of .out files that would be read manually for logging purposes, I'm building a Python script to automate this.

When the script gets to the following

```
for file in os.listdir(DIR_NAME):
    if (file.endswith('.out')):
        open(file)
```

The script blows up with the following error "IOError : No such file or directory: 'Filename.out' "

I've a similar function with the above code and works fine, only it reads .err files.  Printing out DIR_NAME before the above code also shows the correct directory is being pointed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns only filenames, not full paths. Use `os.path.join()` to create a full path:

```
for file in os.listdir(DIR_NAME):
    if (file.endswith('.out')):
        open(os.path.join(DIR_NAME, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative that I find a bit easier and flexible to use:

```
import glob,os

for outfile in glob.glob( os.path.join(DIR_NAME, '*.out') ):
    open(outfile)
```

Glob will also accept things like `'*/*.out'` or `'*something*.out'`. I also read files of certain types and have found this to be very handy.